# Do all serial ports on an Arduino MEGA 2560 have the potential to "brick" attached items when being flashed?

Tags: serial, uploading

I was browsing through the [hookup guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/obd-ii-uart-hookup-guide) for SparkFun's OBD-II UART breakout and found something particularly worrying written half way down in a quite casually presented way:

> Keep in mind when you upload this to your board, you will want to disconnect the OBD-II board RX line from the Arduino TX-0, to prevent issues during code upload, such as bricking the OBD-II board.

For my money I think bricking your device should come with a more stark warning than one stuffed part way down a guide starting with "keep in mind" and continuing with "issues". Nonetheless it caught my attention as I tend to build sealed boxes that aren't sprawled in front of a keyboard ready to be rewired any time a re-flash might happen.

Is the real risk here the fact that all of the flashed data would stream past the RX pin of the UART board and potentially accidentally send a 'self-destruct' signal? (Also I'm not sure a system is really up to scratch if you can accidentally tell it to kill itself.)

Surely the programming port is not the one being borrowed by the UART hookup? On a MEGA 2560, using a different serial port, is this still a risk or is that only on boards with one serial port?

Comment: fwiw, when updating ESP8266s, even via OTA, i'll often see the GPIO's "go nuts". On my light dimmers, that means the light is flashing and dimming rapidly and randomly. if it were more complex than a dimmer, it could be a very bad thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Sparkfun example the Arduino Uno is used. The Uno has only one hardware serial port, and that is used to upload a sketch and for the serial monitor. Pin 0 (RX) and pin 1 (TX) can be overriden for something else. However, then you must know what you are doing, and connect and disconnect modules as required.

The Arduino Leonardo and (Pro) Micro use a USB CDC implementation and have a unused hardware serial port at pin 0 and 1.

The Arduino Mega 2560 uses the hardware serial port at pin 0 and 1 to upload a sketch, just as the Uno. However, the three other hardware serial ports are not used, and you are free to use them.

If you use an unused hardware serial port for the OBD-II, there is no risk at all. You can use that port and nothing else messes with that port.

If you use a serial port that is also used to upload a sketch, or a software implementation of a serial port, you probably are going to make a mistake some day, and there is a risk to send the wrong data to the wrong hardware.

[**ADDED**]
I see that the example code in the SparkfunHookup Guide uses the Arduino Uno and SoftwareSerial on pin 2 and 3. That is independent of the hardware serial port. The SoftwareSerial is something that should be used as a last resort, since it almost completely takes over the Arduino board. It's good to have SoftwareSerial, but try to avoid it.
If you do want to use an Arduino Uno, perhaps the [AltSoftSerial](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_AltSoftSerial.html) can be used. The AltSoftSerial works okay for 9600 baud as long as no other code uses too much time in interrupts and no one else uses TIMER1.